# How to define number of decimals in Kotlin/JS?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

Let's imagine something like this:

```kotlin
var num: Float = 0.0f
num = 2.4 * 3.5 / 3.8
```

`num` has several decimals, but I want only 2.

In JS I would use `num.toFixed(2)`.

Other answers here suggest to use `"%.2f".format(num)` or `num.format(2)`. The latter needs a custom extension function:

```kotlin
fun Double.format(digits: Int) = java.lang.String.format("%.${digits}f", this)
```

However, any of these options leads to a compiler error of "unresolved reference". I don't think is a question of imports cause the compiler would suggest it.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you try to compile Kotlin to JS?

Comment: Yes, that is what they're doing.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61225315/8583692

Answer (score 12):

Kotlin standard library for JS doesn't have anything like `Double.format` yet, but you can implement it easily with aforementioned [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function available in javascript:

```
fun Double.format(digits: Int): String = this.asDynamic().toFixed(digits)
fun Float.format(digits: Int): String = this.asDynamic().toFixed(digits)
```

This works because `Double` and `Float` in Kotlin are represented with `Number` data type in JS, so you can call `toFixed()` function on instances of those types.

Comment: Nice! That worked, thanks! However you mistake in call `toFixed()`, you have to call `format()`. So in my example would be `num.format(2)`. To be said also that this also convert `Float` to `String`, so better called when have to print it