# Is there a way in Kotlin Multiplatform to format a float to a number of decimal places?

Tags: string, kotlin, floating-point, type-conversion, kotlin-multiplatform

Most of the answers use Java (e.g. `String.format`) to get the job done, but I need a way to do this purely with Kotlin to support multiplatform programming.

This means not using `java.*` standard packages.

Say a method like fun Float.toString(numOfDec: Int). I'd like the value to round e.g.:

`35.229938f.toString(1)` should return `35.2`

`35.899991f.toString(2)` should return `35.90`

Comment: Note to folks providing alternative solutions... They need to be Kotlin Common/JVM/JS/Native... not one's that only work on the JVM (for example String.format).

Comment: This wording is a bit confusing. By "native Kotlin" do you mean "Kotlin Native"?

Comment: Yes... was being to glib/not precise... the component we're writing targets/runs on both iOS and Android

Answer (score 5):

If you want to return a float, but only to remove the trailing decimals use this:

```
fun Float.roundToDecimals(decimals: Int): Float {
    var dotAt = 1
    repeat(decimals) { dotAt *= 10 }
    val roundedValue = (this * dotAt).roundToInt()
    return (roundedValue / dotAt) + (roundedValue % dotAt).toFloat() / dotAt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the following Float extension (this should also work with Double):

```
/**
 * Return the float receiver as a string display with numOfDec after the decimal (rounded)
 * (e.g. 35.72 with numOfDec = 1 will be 35.7, 35.78 with numOfDec = 2 will be 35.80)
 *
 * @param numOfDec number of decimal places to show (receiver is rounded to that number)
 * @return the String representation of the receiver up to numOfDec decimal places
 */
fun Float.toString(numOfDec: Int): String {
    val integerDigits = this.toInt()
    val floatDigits = ((this - integerDigits) * 10f.pow(numOfDec)).roundToInt()
    return "${integerDigits}.${floatDigits}"
}
```

Comment: There's a problem with this code. Consider 0.01.toString(2), it will return "0.1" instead of "0.01" as leading zeros on the decimal parts is dropped.

Comment: It also makes mistakes on negative values; -1.01 -> "-1.-1"

Answer (score 0):

I needed to format some numbers to a max amount of decimals so [I whipped out this in the playground](https://pl.kotl.in/WfLCd2NaH):

```
import kotlin.math.min

fun <T> limitDecimals(input: T, maxDecimals: Int): String {
    val result = input.toString()
    val lastIndex = result.length - 1
    var pos = lastIndex
    while (pos >= 0 && result[pos] != '.') {
        pos--
    }
    return if (maxDecimals < 1 && pos >= 0) {
        result.substring(0, min(pos, result.length))       
    } else if (pos >= 0) {
        result.substring(0, min(pos + 1 + maxDecimals, result.length))
    } else {
        return result
    }
}


fun main() {
    val a = 34.1f
    val b = -3.123456789876543217878
    
    println("$a -> ${limitDecimals(a, 2)}")
    println("$b -> ${limitDecimals(b, 5)}")
    println("$b -> ${limitDecimals(b, 100)}")
}
```

The output of this code would be:

```
34.1 -> 34.1
-3.1234567898765433 -> -3.12345
-3.1234567898765433 -> -3.1234567898765433
```

However, this does not cover the rounding up of decimals. Once you find the last character in the string it is easy to check for the next one and see if you need to carry over… but that soon balloons to an iteration over the rest of the string to carry over, and perform different rounding for negative numbers… it was out of the scope for my needs so I'm leaving before I get too tangled up in this and let somebody else finish up.

Answer (score -3):

Use this in your scenario

```
 try {
            if (!TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(st)) {
                val rounded = Math.round(st.toFloat())
                val toHex = BigInteger(rounded.toString(), 10)
                val t = toHex.toString(16)
                t.toString()
            } else {
                val toHex = BigInteger(st, 10)
                val t = toHex.toString(16)
                t.toString()
            }
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            error
        }
```

Comment: As mentioned the solution needs to use native Kotlin as this is for a multiplatform project so no Java classes/methods/packages can be involved